# bash + timer in dialog window

Tags: bash, shell-script, clock, dialog

Is it possible to insert the following code ( a timer ) in the [dialog](http://invisible-island.net/dialog/dialog.html) progress bar ?

```
date1=`date +%s`; 
   while true; do 
   echo -ne "$(date -u --date @$((`date +%s` - $date1)) +%H:%M:%S)\r"; 
  done
```

...

```
  dialog --title "File upgrade" --gauge "Please wait..." 10 70 0
```

My goal is to view the timer clock in the progress bar window.
The clock should stop when the progress bar ended.

Answer (score 2):

I would avoid any arithmetic operation, and use `--gauge` as documented ("new percentages are read from standard input"):

```
for ((i=0;i<=100;i+=10)); do echo $i; sleep 1; done | dialog --gauge "Please wait 10 seconds." 0 0
```

Comment: `{, } => do, done` ?

Comment: You can use both syntaxes in Bash, but this one allows to specify the increment.

Comment: Maybe you can :D. I would love to use the curly brace syntax but bash 4.3.11 won't allow me to. Neither will ksh, csh or dash. Zsh will. Aren't you on zsh?

Comment: You're totally right, I've tested it using zsh. I use the curly braces in scripts, but it seems it doesn't work on a single line... I've updated the answer accordingly.